# Iterating over an enum in a Predicate?

Tags: java

I'm trying to loop over an enum in a predicate to return the proper values that I need.

Here's what I would do :

```
private Predicate<Item> isCorrectItem() {
    for (Thing thing : Thing.values()) {
        return item -> item.getId() == thing.getNumber();
    }
}
```

except java wants a return outside of the loop aswell. Returning null after the loop won't do me any good. I'm asking, what can I do to either avoid returning twice or to avoid iterating over the enum in the first place? And if not, what
should I return?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you want your predicate to do. Is it meant to see whether *any* of the things has the value in the item? Any reason you don't want to have a `HashSet<Integer>` (or whatever) for all the "thing numbers"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Item` is correct when it has a matching `number` in the `enum Thing` you can use

```
private Predicate<Item> isCorrectItem() {
    return item -> Arrays.stream(Thing.values()).anyMatch(thing -> thing.getNumber() == item.getId());
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@garnulf's answer (or @Tunaki's?) is correct, but just for context, here's what you probably meant in your question:

```
private Predicate<Item> isCorrectItem() {
    return item -> {
        for (Thing thing : Thing.values()) {
            if (item.getId() == thing.getNumber()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
}
```